# how to select all spesific column name, in multiple table with identical table name in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one database for my website, and in one script i've been created script with auto create table every month.

This my example table :

Table user_2016_09

```
| id | unique_id | created at |
-------------------------------
| 1  | abcdefg   | 02082016   |
```

Table user_2016_10

```
| id | unique_id | created at |
-------------------------------
| 1  | hijklmn   | 02082016   |
```

and continue until table user_2017_01 with different data, but same column name and has identicall table name. how to select all unique_id in all month in 2016 ?

Comment: Take a look at the [MERGE Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html)

Comment: im try to select all, not create table again

Comment: If you created a union table, you only have to do it once. Then you can use that table to select from all the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union

```
select unique_id
from user_2016_09
union 
select unique_id
from user_2016_10
union 
select unique_id
from user_2016_11
.....
```

Comment: if I want to select from user_2017_01 until user_2019_01 , must i created union again and again ? no other way ?

Comment: If you need  the distinct value this is a way .. if you want you could generate  automatically the  code using a server side .. language ..  or create once  ..

Comment: @christan_dk You can use dynamic SQL to create the union using a query from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.